# XWAMP, PHP: page is empty when trying to open localhost/tests/test.php

Tags: php, xampp

I am following the php tutorial on the french platform"openclassrooms".

I am using Linux Ubuntu.

I installed XWAMPP, I launched it from the terminal:
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.1.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

I saved an HTML/PHP file with the php extension at /opt/lampp/htdocs/tests
The file is called test.php and when I try to open it from the browser (chrome and Mozilla) like this http://localhost/tests/test.php
I get an empty page without error messages. Only the tab title appears.

Thank your for your help!

[image]

Comment: So what do you have in that file?

Comment: Yea. try to echo some text

Comment: You didn't closed you `<title>` tag...

Comment: Check your servers error log and right click on the page and choose "view source" to see what the output actually looks like.

Comment: Do you mean `XAMPP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your picture your didn't closed your `<title>` tag appropriately. You made spelling mistake - you have `</tile>` closing tag instead of `</title>`...

Comment: Accept his answer and close the question

Comment: Hello Baji, I accepted the question but it was not possible to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to begin your code with starting php tag `<?php` and closing tag `?>`
if you miss especially the closing tag you code will apperar as a simple HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the screenshot you haven't closed your  tag. You've put  change this to  which should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The problem was solved but I do not know how to close the question.